# How to load the preimage of a video in HTML5

Tags: angularjs, html5-video

I have developed a website which loads videos like youtube. The main problem I am facing is being able to load the pre-image of the video instead of the whole video loading in the browser. Only when the user clicks to play the video it should load in the browser. The main reason I would like to achieve this is because too many videos loaded on the page would lead to the page slowing down.

HTML5 code for the video is as follows :

`<video id="videolink" type="video/mp4" ng-src="{{v.video_path}}" controls ></video>`

Comment: Put up a thumbnail image and then on click of the thumbnail image load the video in it's place

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-if` to remove the video and replace it with an image. The only caveat with this method is you have to have an image of the video to show

```
<video id="videolink" type="video/mp4" ng-src="{{v.video_path}}" controls ng-if="doplay"></video>
<img ng-src="{{v.video_thumbnail}}" ng-if="!doplay"/>
```